# Post is not sending Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I made a Login page which should post Username & Password. I Have used Axios. This username and password I wrapped into an object (check the below code), but after submitting, I am getting "201" response. Yes, it's working, but in Chrome Browser -> Network -> Request Payload showing like this

```
{"name":"[object Undefined]","password":"[object Undefined]"}
```

This is my code

```js
class UserLogin extends React.Component {
    createUser = () => {
        let getLoginName = document.getElementById('user_name');
        let getLoginPassword = document.getElementById('user_pass');
        let postData = {
            name: toString(getLoginName),
            password: toString(getLoginPassword)
        }
        axios.post('https://reqres.in/api/users', postData)
            .then((function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }))
            .catch((function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }))
    }
```

This is my API

```json
{
    "email": "xxx@yyy.com",
    "password": "helloworld"
}
```

Comment: Please post your `toString()` method. Additionally: `console.log(getLoginName, getLoginPassword)`. Do the fields exist? Is it showing you the element?

Comment: Not working @FrankerZ.. Yes those files are exist...If i give hardcoded username and password like a string its working

Comment: What do you mean not working? Nothing I asked would change anything...they're logging functions intended to give us more information about your problem. Add that `console.log()` line right after `let getLoginPassword = document.getElementById('user_pass');` and post the resulting output from your console. Additionally, post your `toString()` method.

Comment: Unfortunately without a proper [mcve], I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. Please add in the details I've mentioned, so that we can properly assist you.

Comment: *Please*, indent your code and use one [indenting style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) consistently throughout your code. Doing so makes it **much** easier to read/maintain. As a side effect, doing so for code you place on Stack Overflow makes it much more likely that you will get people to up-vote your posts and makes it more likely that people will put time into Answering your Questions. It doesn't matter which style your choose (although, IMO, some are more appropriate for JavaScript than others). But, pick one and use it consistently for all code in a single project.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
 let postData =  JSON.stringify({

   username: getLoginName,
   password: getLoginPassword

});
```

Comment: I am getting Error "Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"

Comment: can you console log your getLoginName and getLoginPassword?

Answer (score -2):

You need the brackets if you want to send it as an object so send it like this

```
 axios.post('https://reqres.in/api/users', {
   data: postData}).then( response => {
 console.log(response);
  })
```

how are you requesting the data in api?

Comment: tell me why its not true? :D im using this on my calls?  and im asking so he can log if he gets anything in the api? so don't comment if  you don't know what you are talking about?

Comment: You may be using it in your calls, but it's completely unnecessary, and actually creates an unneeded data structure `{data: actualDataHere}`. You would need to then access it in the backend using something like `$_POST['data']['key']` instead of just `$_POST['key']`.

Comment: True,  thats the only thing, something small structure just to illustrate for him what im doing? don't go downvoting for such a small thing? it can be a good practice to do if you're sending more objects and stuff. Overall this is a working method

Comment: But your saying that is required if he wants to send it as an object. This is simply not true. OP already pointed out additionally that he's seeing `{"name":"[object Undefined]","password":"[object Undefined]"}` in his request payload, so the fact the keys are present means he has an issue with his `toString()` method, or his `document.getElementById` aren't returning elements. All this accomplishes is rewriting the request to: ``{"data": {"name":"[object Undefined]","password":"[object Undefined]"}}``

Comment: he can just type JSON.stringify(object) and then send it, should do the work but also for correcting his way of posting his axios.

Comment: But again: There is nothing wrong with his post request to axios. When you use `axios.post`, the second parameter is explicitly setting the data property to the parameter passed. By specifically defining it, you're creating a double data structure. Your function is essentially functionally identical to this: https://pastebin.com/8TbR582H. And to answer your last statement: axios will already convert the object structure and `JSON.stringify` it, so that's redundant again, and not needed.